# How to communicate third-party approval to customers?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

### Short story

We are running a software company. Today, it's really hard to publish binary files, because of the false positive alarms of antivirus software. By default all executable files that are not recognized are blocked by this software.

After hard work, many antivirus companies approved us. Now our software works for our clients.

### The question

We are looking for a way to tell our users that those companies now approve our binaries. It should be in the footer section of our homepage.

We thought about:

- Approved By: Symantec, McAfee, ...
- Verified By: Symantec, McAfee, ...
- Trusted By: Symantec, McAfee, ...
- Clean By: Symantec, McAfee, ...

I'm not sure what should be the most accurate and concise way to explain that those antivirus companies found that our software is free from malware, trojans, and viruses.

Comment: A marketing question.

Comment: @Xanne: It's not a marketing question, I didn't link to any website, and I didn't mention the name of the software. (And we didn't launched yet)

Comment: My gut feeling is that "verified" is best, but it's just that, a gut feeling. Do the antivirus makers have a standard word to describe their process?

Comment: Anyway: certified by.

Comment: Definitely not 'Clean By', which implies they may have cleaned it, not 'Trusted By', because that is ambiguous and does not necessarily mean that they checked it - I'd go for 'Approved By' or 'Verified By', and I agree with Felix that 'Verified' sounds better.

Comment: Thanks @Lee Leon, Felix & Xanne. How is it sounds : *Verified safe by:*